# jupyter notebook python version 2.7.13 (print invalid syntax error)

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

Hi I have a Jupyter Notebook, with python 2.7.13 and it worked fine all along. But starting today it shows strange behaviour.

when I do this in a fresh notebook Python 2:

```
print 'hello'
```

it returns this:

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-bfbe230352b8>", line 1
    print 'hello'
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It was working ok till yesterday and today I restarted the computer and this happens.

Any reasons? How to fix?

I have checked anaconda, spyder, command prompt... everywhere else is ok with 2.7.13

`print ('hello')` works but I don't want this.. all my code is in Python 2.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now tracked the problem to be caused by the extension. Once I rename this file `C:\Users\X\.jupyter\nbconfig\notebook.json` to something else and reopen jupyter notebook, the print works as expected.

However, I do need the extensions at least the key ones I use regularly. I don't know which one to disable. I didn't know how to track the culprit without going through each one by one. Also, as far as I can remember, all the extensions I have been using for few weeks already without any issues.

These are the contents of the notebook.json file.

```
{
  "load_extensions": {
    "toc2/main": true, 
    "Runtools": true, 
    "collapsible_headings/main": true, 
    "codefolding/main": true, 
    "varInspector/main": true, 
    "runtools/main": true, 
    "runtools": true
  }, 
  "collapsible_headings": {
    "add_button": true, 
    "add_insert_header_buttons": true
  }
}
```

After trial and error with disabling one every time, restart and check.. I have now solved the problem by setting this line to false, it now works. The problem is with variable inspector extension.

```
"varInspector/main": false,
```

Sometimes the jupyter required a restart and sometime it didn't. Just opening the .ipynb file was enough to test.

I have the same extension running in my office computer, which has no issues.

If someone could really put in the comments for the cause and a solution for permanent fix of this problem will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with reloading sys like below ?

```
import sys
reload(sys)
print 'hello'
```

Comment: it returns the same... ```SyntaxError: invalid syntax```. nevertheless thanks for your reply... this is driving me nuts!

Comment: above problem is in my home pc. i repeat the print problem is in my home pc. OK. Now, however in my office pc, i have the same setup and there are NO ISSUES. But, when i ran the above commands from you ```reload(sys)```.. it caused havoc.. all the print went to the jupyter notebook console (the black background webserver console).. instead of the notebook in browser itself. This was strange for me. After the restart of the notebook.. things got back to normal in my office pc. Anyone know what  caused the print to be sent to console. (in my home pc, the problem remains)